# itemtemplate in inner nested repeater can not be fired properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

innner OnItemDataBound event （itemtype） should be hit twice, as here I have 2 children. 
But whatever I try, it is only been hitted once. Any thoughts?

Data structure:
Parent
A

Children
X
Y

Frontend:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ParentRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ItemBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <!-- Repeated data -->
        <asp:Repeater ID="ChildRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="InnerItemBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdxyz" runat="server" Value="false"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Backend:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ParentRepeater.DataSource = ...;
            ParentRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void ItemBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            Repeater childRepeater = (Repeater)args.Item.FindControl("ChildRepeater");
            childRepeater.DataSource = ...;
            childRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }


protected void InnerItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
  {
    //Should be hit twice, as here I have 2 children. 
    //But whatever I try, it only hit once.
    bindHiddenFieldInRepeater(e, "hdxyz", "hdEventID");

    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess I've you'd have 3 items, the event would be fired twice, instead of thrice.

Try `if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)`

Comment: What a great hint. I should post this question 2 hours ago. But why? I put control in itemtemplate rather than a AlternatingItemTemplate template.